# Copy a Range of Cells x-times

Tags: vba, excel

In a workbook I have two Tables; TAB1 that contains the formulas for the calculations, and TAB2 that contains the data to calculate.

Range TAB1.cells(1, 1) : Range TAB1.cells(20, 1) that contains the formulas and which need to be copied to the right x-times.

Range TAB1.cells(25, 1) : Range TAB1.cells(25, x) that contains the formulas and which need to be copied down y-times.

Whereas     x = number of columns with data in TAB2
Whereas     y = number of rows with data in TAB2

I have tried to use the following VBA but I receive an error:

```
Sub DataCopy()
Dim RowMax As Integer
Dim ColMax As Integer

    Sheets("Data").Select
    Range("A1").Select

    RowMax = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    ColMax = Cells(2, Columns.Count).End(xlToRight).Column

    Range(1, 1).Select
    Range(RowMax, ColMax).Select

    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Calc").Select
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Range("A1").Select

End Sub
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: This is not a question but a set of requirements.  What *exactly* is preventing you from doing this? What have you tried (include your existing code), and what happened?

Comment: Simply record a macro while you do it, save it and re-run it when required.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I have created a macro and tried to make a VBA using it. But I receive an error.

I have added the code to my question so that it is better to read.

Comment: You've got many problems with the above code. A bunch of useless select statements (two in a row = one useless, plus select is useless by itself). xlToRight should probably be replaced by xlToLeft if you're trying to find the last column. Range(1,1) can't be used. Cells(1,1) yes.
Your code right now, even if it was written correctly, would only select the cell on the last used row of column A and the last column of the sheet "Data" and would copy it to A1.
Record something that makes sense, and run it with F8 (step by step) to see what it's doing...

Comment: Thanks Julien, that explains a lot. But what is the correct code to define the respective range to be able to copy it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I have answered your code error issue. You should review to see if correct. Then you should take your others issue(s) and create a separate question. There is too much going on to be answered succinctly with one question.

Comment: You were down-voted to let other users know that the quality of the question is low. I gave you tips as to what you could do to clean up the question. Read [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more information. I will also be editing your question to remove your comment about the downvotes. This is a great site. Spend some time and understand how it works to get the most out it!

Comment: OK, I am new to this forum and already now I love it. The edit of my question will help me to ask my questions in the right way from now on :)! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sub DataCopy()
    Dim RowMax As Integer
    Dim ColMax As Integer

    RowMax = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    ColMax = Cells(2, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    Range(Cells(1, 1),Cells(RowMax,ColMax)).Copy
    Sheets("Calc").Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = FALSE
End Sub
```